Closed form solution of T(n) = 5T(n−1) + n^2, to T(1) = 7
How to find the closed form solution of this equation?
T(n) = 5T(n−1) + n^2, to T(1) = 7

https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2789/755

Does this answer your question? Solving or approximating recurrence relations for sequences of numbers

Simply follow the substitution chain: $T(n) = 5T(n-1) + n^2 = 5^2T(n-2) + 5(n-1)^2 + n^2 = \dots$. After that, it should be straight-forward enough.
